# Error in Eval() while executing javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create `sprites` for my application using open id selectorAPI.
They have a [JS file](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/source/browse/trunk/generate-sprite.js) which take help from Image magic to create sprite image.

I have followed there instructions and trying to run JS file using this command

```
wscript generate-sprite.js
```

[image: Error Screen Shot]

But I am getting following error.Can any one help me to understand issue?
Some part of JS file

### JS file

```
var imagemagick = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.6.5-Q16/';

var locale = 'en';
if (WScript.Arguments.length == 0) {
        // assuming english locale
} else {
        locale = WScript.Arguments(0);
}

var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

var s;
var f = fso.OpenTextFile('js/openid-' + locale + '.js');
try {
        s = f.ReadAll();
} finally {
        f.Close();
}
var openid = {};
eval(s);

eval is on line35 in that script
```

### openid-en.js

```
/*
    Simple OpenID Plugin
    http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

    This code is licensed under the New BSD License.
*/

var providers_large = {
    BD : {
     name: 'BD',
     url: "BD"
   },
    GOOGLE : {
        name : 'Google',
        url : 'GOOGLE'
    },
    FACEBOOK : {
     name: 'Facebook',
     url: "FACEBOOK"
   },

   MSN : {
     name: 'MSN',
     url: "MSN"
   }

var providers_small = {
    livejournal : {
        name : 'LiveJournal',
        label : 'Enter your Livejournal username.',
        url : 'http://{username}.livejournal.com/'
    },
    /* flickr: {
        name: 'Flickr',        
        label: 'Enter your Flickr username.',
        url: 'http://flickr.com/{username}/'
    }, */
    /* technorati: {
        name: 'Technorati',
        label: 'Enter your Technorati username.',
        url: 'http://technorati.com/people/technorati/{username}/'
    }, */
    wordpress : {
        name : 'Wordpress',
        label : 'Enter your Wordpress.com username.',
        url : 'http://{username}.wordpress.com/'
    },
    blogger : {
        name : 'Blogger',
        label : 'Your Blogger account',
        url : 'http://{username}.blogspot.com/'
    },
    verisign : {
        name : 'Verisign',
        label : 'Your Verisign username',
        url : 'http://{username}.pip.verisignlabs.com/'
    },
    /* vidoop: {
        name: 'Vidoop',
        label: 'Your Vidoop username',
        url: 'http://{username}.myvidoop.com/'
    }, */
    /* launchpad: {
        name: 'Launchpad',
        label: 'Your Launchpad username',
        url: 'https://launchpad.net/~{username}'
    }, */
    claimid : {
        name : 'ClaimID',
        label : 'Your ClaimID username',
        url : 'http://claimid.com/{username}'
    },
    clickpass : {
        name : 'ClickPass',
        label : 'Enter your ClickPass username',
        url : 'http://clickpass.com/public/{username}'
    },
    google_profile : {
        name : 'Google Profile',
        label : 'Enter your Google Profile username',
        url : 'http://www.google.com/profiles/{username}'
    }
};

openid.locale = 'en';
openid.sprite = 'en'; // reused in german& japan localization
openid.demo_text = 'In client demo mode. Normally would have submitted OpenID:';
openid.signin_text = 'Sign-In';
openid.image_title = 'log in with {provider}';
```

Comment: Can you paste _your_ script in 5 lines around line 35?

Comment: Show us your script...

Comment: You have a syntax error in the code.

Comment: Apparently there is a syntax error in `js/openid-en.js` (I hope I expanded it right). Can you give the source of that script?

Comment: @Jivings: I am using JS from third party and have attached url in the post

Comment: @aIKid: added some part of script, also I have provided script url in my post as its a third part js

Comment: @RonakBhatt: I have added script, if needed can add complete js file

Comment: Can you also post the contents of `js/openid-en.js`?

Comment: @user3184646 Is this your script or the one in the link?

Comment: @Jivings: i have provided content from openid-en.js file

Comment: @aIKid:it is one from the link

Comment: @Chiel92: i have provided content from `openid-en.js` file

Comment: Oh sorry, i think it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is apparently a closing bracket missing in `js/openid-en.js`:

```
var providers_large = {
    BD : {
     name: 'BD',
     url: "BD"
   },
    GOOGLE : {
        name : 'Google',
        url : 'GOOGLE'
    },
    FACEBOOK : {
     name: 'Facebook',
     url: "FACEBOOK"
   },

   MSN : {
     name: 'MSN',
     url: "MSN"
   }
// There should be a closing bracket here!
```

Comment: I can't see it: https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/source/browse/trunk/js/openid-en.js

Comment: Try again now. Think I pasted it wrong.

Comment: It isn't there indeed, but it differs in more ways from what the OP pasted, so he probably edited the original script it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var providers_large = {
    BD : {
     name: 'BD',
     url: "BD"
   },
    GOOGLE : {
        name : 'Google',
        url : 'GOOGLE'
    },
    FACEBOOK : {
     name: 'Facebook',
     url: "FACEBOOK"
   },

   MSN : {
     name: 'MSN',
     url: "MSN"
   }
 };
```

you have missed this last '};'

Answer (score 0):

Missing a closing curly braces here:

```
var providers_large = {
    BD : {
     name: 'BD',
     url: "BD"
   },
    GOOGLE : {
        name : 'Google',
        url : 'GOOGLE'
    },
    FACEBOOK : {
     name: 'Facebook',
     url: "FACEBOOK"
   },

   MSN : {
     name: 'MSN',
     url: "MSN"
   }
}; // Added! :)
```

Hope thsi helps!